# characterization of the unipotent radical of a linear algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-groups

Im having difficulties understanding a ceratain argument in the following proof, taken from T.A springer's linear algebraic groups.

In the following proof C is the intersection of the unipotent parts of all borel groups containing the maximal torus T, and C<sub>$\alpha$</sub> is the intersection of the unipotent parts all such borel groups for wich $\alpha$ is a positive root.
[image]

I dont understand why should the borel groups be contained in TC or TC<sub>$\alpha$</sub>

Answer (score -1):

The heuristic is as follows: The toral (and abelian) subgroup allows us to simultaneously diagonalize them, such that $C$ are all upper triangular matrices with ones on the diagonal (unipotent). Then $C_\alpha T=TC_\alpha$ is a Borel subgroup (maximal solvable). The fact that $\alpha$ is a positive root, fixes the root system and so the possible conjugates. Adding any other generator would mean to add a negative root and destroy solvability.